# What do we do with low quality answers from high rep users?

Tags: discussion, answers

*Note: if I directly point you out, please don't take it personal*

I've noticed for some time now that while I've been cleaning up, that there are quite a few active, higher rep users, that are posting what is to be considered [low quality answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/75278/high-rep-users-with-farquaad-syndrome?Reputation=10000&AnswerLength=140) (or in reality short answers).  For example:

- https://superuser.com/questions/147175/wubi-installer-available-for-suse-linux/147206#147206
- [Print the file name with another extension (Batch-program)](https://superuser.com/questions/131966/print-the-file-name-with-another-extension-batch-program/132091#132091)
- https://superuser.com/questions/142274/sending-e-mails-that-cannot-be-forwarded/142275#142275
- https://superuser.com/questions/41050/can-i-fake-the-amount-of-vram-i-have-on-my-computer/41053#41053
- [How can I open a file read-only from command line with emacs/vi/vim](https://superuser.com/questions/204236/how-can-i-open-a-file-read-only-from-command-line-with-emacs-vi-vim/204238#204238)
- https://superuser.com/questions/34417/desktop-bulk-emailer-suggestion/34419#34419
- [What would cause ripple interference on a monitor display attached to computer via VGA?](https://superuser.com/questions/387383/what-would-cause-ripple-interference-on-a-monitor-display-attached-to-computer-v/387385#387385)
- https://superuser.com/questions/131344/best-software-for-creating-icons/304275#304275
- [Stop Windows 7 from searching while I’m typing in the search field, and wait for me to press Enter](https://superuser.com/questions/253731/stop-windows-7-from-searching-while-im-typing-in-the-search-field-and-wait-for/269535#269535)
- [My windows directory is huge](https://superuser.com/questions/307869/my-windows-directory-is-huge/307881#307881)

And many many more....

My question is this.  While technically correct, these answers are very short, and typcially not helpful to the community most times, while the other times, it's an indicator of a terrible question.  Should we edit, flag, close the question, comment the answer?  I have been mainly ignoring them, but feel that there are plenty enough that we should probably address this issue.

Comment: As an aside, third from last is not constructive.

Comment: You know, not to knock on anyone personally, but some people with tons of rep have tons of rep because they post a whole lot of short, quick, easy answers. Carpet bomb and hope you get some success.

Comment: @nhinkle I've seen this as well, and that's what I'm asking here.  Do we just let them be and stop new users from doing so?  Or do we clean this up as we go along?

Comment: Treat it the same you would as if they didn't have such a high reputation.

Comment: [This](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/75319/high-rep-users-with-farquaad-syndrome) query is useful for users wanting to audit their own posts.

Comment: Sometimes a short answer is all you need. Eg. how would you suggest that the [open read only](http://superuser.com/questions/204236/how-can-i-open-a-file-read-only-from-command-line-with-emacs-vi-vim/204238#204238) answer be made better?

Comment: @Richard those are IMO few and far between and even with yours it's *possible* to expand to the others that he requested, thus giving you a little more room to add. Nonetheless, there are going to be a few **rare** question like that one where a simple short answer is sufficient.

Comment: @KronoS In my experience (mostly on [SO] rather than here) there are lots of questions where the answer is short. Any expansion is just pointless verbosity. Which is why, in my previous comment, I ask for specifics not generalities.

Comment: @Richard I didn't realize that you were looking for specifics.  In that case, I agree that the short is answer is about the best that can be given.

Comment: If the question can be answered with a simple yes or no, its probably not a good question to begin with

Comment: @DarthAndroid Thanks for linking to the query.

Comment: Thanks, too, from me for the query. I found some shoddy answers of my own which I've either deleted or improved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind:

- If the question is crap, deal with it like we would do with any other. Vote to close or delete right away. If there really are high rep users who repeatedly answer bad questions with their one line of code, then let the deletion be a sign for them — don't answer crap questions! If you want to conserve your reputation and have your content stay around, you'll also have to make sure the question won't be deleted.
- If the question itself is fine, post a comment on the answer, asking them to expand it. High rep users should really know better, and even one line of code can be explained. Yes, it can *cough* … and most high-rep users are active enough to see your comment and add a little more detail once they're asked to.

All in all, I think our goal is clear. Users who have a lot of reputation should lead the community by example – and part of this involves posting great answers where possible. Now, this obviously isn't always doable, especially for cases where the answer is "no, you can't", but I think you can always manage *not* to land in the "low quality" queue. Now, you won't be notified of that automatically, but if someone is asking you to improve your post because it was marked low quality, why not take that as an opportunity to make this site better?

I'm not sure we've ever done something about these kinds of high-rep users who constantly post "low quality" answers — and I'm sure some examples come to mind — but that would be something better discussed privately and not here, on Meta.

To summarize, I'd suggest to continue acting on a case-by-case basis. Leave a comment if possible and see if that results in better answers. There's not much else I can think of.

Comment: Just as a FYI, this was NOT meant to point out any single user.  I would never do that publicly here on Meta, but rather in a more private setting (chat, or email if possible and after consulting a moderator).  This was mainly to A. bring awareness to those high rep users that may do this, and B. determine a plan of action that I can reference in case there is any blow back due to my actions.

Comment: Yeah, got you there — like I said, if there are "repeated offenders", then that's something different. I guess your question was more about the occasional low quality posts that tend to show up once in a while.

Comment: Only twice (only once recently for an answer posted over a year ago) have I been asked to expand the answer I gave. With my rep, I definitely felt embarrassed I used to think that was acceptable, but I would agree that we need to post better answers all the time. As for not being on the Low Quality review page... Is it possible to learn what the checker uses so we can make sure we don't land on there BEFORE the answer gets posted?

Comment: Mostly these are rather old answers. Perhaps those hig-rep-users where new to the site then... Anyhow, I think we should treat them the same as any other answer, flag for removal or edit if salvageable.

Comment: @Luke No, I don't think so — unless you check the low quality queue yourself. The thing is: Some quality filters are deactivated at a certain point of reputation level, so basically, I can write as many low quality answers as I want.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest the following auto comments for low quality answers that are still worth keeping:

#### High Rep Low Quality:

*Statement*

> As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and
>   [add more
>   detail](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users).

*Code:*

```
###High Rep Low Quality
As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and [add more detail](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users).
```

#### Low Rep Low Quality:

*Statement*

> Welcome to Super User! I suggest you [add more
>   detail](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users)
>   to this question so that it can be more useful to future users.  For
>   example you could .

*Code:*

```
###Low Rep Low Quality
Welcome to Super User! I suggest you [add more detail](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users) to this question so that it can be more useful to future users.  For example you could <MaterialForImprovement>.
```